# I encountered some problems when I tried to connect the chaincode with the go program.* '***.Registrar' expected a map, got 'slice'

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I wrote the configuration file connect.yaml and tried to connect the chaincode with the go program. But the following error occurred:

2021/08/29 17:10:04 Failed to connect to gateway: Failed to apply config option: failed to initialize configuration: unable to load identity config: failed to initialize identity config from config backend: failed to create identity config from backends: failed to parse 'certificateAuthorities' config item to identityConfigEntity.CertificateAuthorities type: 3 error(s) decoding:

- '[ca.agridepart.amops.com].Registrar' expected a map, got 'slice'
- '[ca.agrimacowner.amops.com].Registrar' expected a map, got 'slice'
- '[ca.financedepart.amops.com].Registrar' expected a map, got 'slice'

Then I tried to delete the following content in the certificateAuthorities section in the connect.yaml file

```
registrar:
     -enrollId: admin
       enrollSecret: adminpw
```

But the following error occurred：
2021/08/29 17:38:57 Failed to get network: Failed to create new channel client: event service creation failed: could not get chConfig cache reference: QueryBlockConfig failed: QueryBlockConfig failed: target(s) required

So whether the second error is related to the first error and what caused it. what should I do?

The content of my connect.yaml file is as follows:

```
---
name: amops
version: 1.0.0
client:
  organization: Agridepart
  connection:
    timeout:
      peer:
        endorser: '300'
      orderer: '300'
channels:
  amops:
    orderers:
    - agridepartorderer.amops.com
    - agrimacownerorderer.amops.com
    - financedepartorderer.amops.com
    peers:
      peer0.agridepart.amops.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true
      peer0.agrimacowner.amops.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true
      peer0.financedepart.amops.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true
organizations:
  Agridepart:
    mspid: AgridepartMSP
    peers:
    - peer0.agridepart.amops.com
    certificateAuthorities:
    - ca.agridepart.amops.com
    adminPrivateKeyPEM:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/agridepart.amops.com/users/Admin@agridepart.amops.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk"
    signedCertPEM:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/agridepart.amops.com/users/Admin@agridepart.amops.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@agridepart.example.com-cert.pem"
  Agrimacowner:
    mspid: AgrimacownerMSP
    peers:
    - peer0.agrimacowner.amops.com
    certificateAuthorities:
    - ca.agrimacowner.amops.com
    adminPrivateKeyPEM:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/agrimacowner.amops.com/users/Admin@agrimacowner.amops.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk"
    signedCertPEM:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/agrimacowner.amops.com/users/Admin@agrimacowner.amops.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@agrimacowner.amops.com-cert.pem"
  Financedepart:
    mspid: FinancedepartMSP
    peers:
    - peer0.financedepart.amops.com
    certificateAuthorities:
    - ca.financedepart.amops.com
    adminPrivateKeyPEM:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/financedepart.amops.com/users/Admin@financedepart.amops.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk"
    signedCertPEM:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/financedepart.amops.com/users/Admin@financedepart.amops.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@financedepart.amops.com-cert.pem"
orderers:
  agridepartorderer.amops.com:
    url: grpcs://192.168.32.165:7050
    mspid: OrdererMSP
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: agridepartorderer.amops.com
      hostnameOverride: agridepartorderer.amops.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/amops.com/orderers/agridepartorderer.amops.com/tls/ca.crt"
    adminPrivateKeyPEM:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/amops.com/users/Admin@amops.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk"
    signedCertPEM:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/amops.com/users/Admin@amops.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@amops.com-cert.pem"
  agrimacownerorderer.amops.com:
    url: grpcs://192.168.32.170:7050
    mspid: OrdererMSP
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: agrimacownerorderer.amops.com
      hostnameOverride: agrimacownerorderer.amops.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/amops.com/orderers/agrimacownerorderer.amops.com/tls/ca.crt"
    adminPrivateKeyPEM:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/amops.com/users/Admin@amops.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk"
    signedCertPEM:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/amops.com/users/Admin@amops.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@amops.com-cert.pem"
  financedepartorderer.amops.com:
    url: grpcs://192.168.32.171:7050
    mspid: OrdererMSP
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: financedepartorderer.amops.com
      hostnameOverride: agrimacownerorderer.amops.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/amops.com/orderers/financedepartorderer.amops.com/tls/ca.crt"
    adminPrivateKeyPEM:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/amops.com/users/Admin@amops.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk"
    signedCertPEM:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/amops.com/users/Admin@amops.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@amops.com-cert.pem"
peers:
  peer0.agridepart.amops.com:
    url: grpcs://192.168.32.165:7051
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.agridepart.amops.com
      hostnameOverride: peer0.agridepart.amops.com
      request-timeout: 120001
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/agridepart.amops.com/peers/peer0.agridepart.amops.com/tls/ca.crt"
  peer0.agrimacowner.amops.com:
    url: grpcs://192.168.32.170:7051
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.agrimacowner.amops.com
      hostnameOverride: peer0.agrimacowner.amops.com
      request-timeout: 120001
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/agrimacowner.amops.com/peers/peer0.agrimacowner.amops.com/tls/ca.crt"
  peer0.financedepart.amops.com:
    url: grpcs://192.168.32.171:7051
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.financedepart.amops.com
      hostnameOverride: peer0.financedepart.amops.com
      request-timeout: 120001
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/financedepart.amops.com/peers/peer0.financedepart.amops.com/tls/ca.crt"
certificateAuthorities:
  ca.agridepart.amops.com:
    url: https://192.168.32.165:7054
    httpOptions:
      verify: true
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/agridepart.amops.com/ca/ca.agridepart.amops.com-cert.pem"
    registrar:
    - enrollId: admin
      enrollSecret: adminpw
  ca.agrimacowner.amops.com:
    url: https://192.168.32.170:7054
    httpOptions:
      verify: true
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/agrimacowner.amops.com/ca/ca.agrimacowner.amops.com-cert.pem"
    registrar:
    - enrollId: admin
      enrollSecret: adminpw
  ca.financedepart.amops.com:
    url: https://192.168.32.171:7054
    httpOptions:
      verify: true
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "/home/jing/go/src/github.com/fabric-samples/amops/multiple-deployment/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/financedepart.amops.com/ca/ca.financedepart.amops.com-cert.pem"
    registrar:
    - enrollId: admin
      enrollSecret: adminpw
```

Comment: Did you try removing that `-` before `enrollId` everywhere? That would make `registrar` a map.

Comment: You are right, it worked. thank you very much. But another error: QueryBlockConfig failed: target(s) required still exists, do you know what might be the reason?